# Can't set React useFormState type property to null despite having set null as an option

Tags: typescript, types

I'm working with Typescript. I have a type with a property 'message' that can be string or null

```
export type State = {
  message: string | null;
};
```

Altough, when trying to set that property to null I get the following type error. It only allows me to set it to string.

```
Types of property 'message' are incompatible.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I'm using the type like this:

```
const initialState = { message: null };
const [state, dispatch] = useFormState(postFiles, initialState);

export async function postFiles(prevState: State, formData: FormData) {
  console.log(formData);
  return {
    message: "Uploaded",
  };
}
```

I've tried setting strictNullChecks to true, but I'm still getting the error. What could it be? is there something I'm missing?

Comment: What is the definition of `useFormState`, particularly its types. Or is that from a library?

Comment: It's from react-dom:

import { useFormState } from "react-dom";

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is because the type of `useFormState` is [as follows](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/64545609abb98e4a40dfd4399eb854b910da5594/types/react-dom/canary.d.ts#L130):

```
    function useFormState<State, Payload>(
        action: (state: Awaited<State>, payload: Payload) => State | Promise<State>,
        initialState: Awaited<State>,
        permalink?: string,
    ): [state: Awaited<State>, dispatch: (payload: Payload) => void];
```

Since `action` is defined as `(state: Awaited<State>, payload: Payload) => State`, that means that the return value of that `action`, in this case `postFiles`, will be automatically *inferred* as `State`.

That return value is an object literal where `message` is a string. That means `initialState: Awaited<State>` evaluates to `string` so your `null` value is not valid.

To fix, explicitly pass the type arguments so TS knows ahead of time what this value can be.

```
const [state, dispatch] = useFormState<State, FormData>(postFiles, initialState);
```